# C# Lambda with no inputs (params)?

Tags: c#, lambda

I was just wondering about this case

```
void exc(Func<int> fn) {
    fn();
}
```

I can do the below

```
public void test() {
    exc(delegate{return 1;});
}
```

However I like the => syntax so i tried

```
public void test() {
    exc(void=>1);
}
```

It didnt compile. Is there a way I may use the => syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost did from the top of your head :). Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more details, but this is what you are looking for:

```
public void test()
{
    exc(()=>1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Func<int>` means a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer. So you could specify it as an anonymous function like this

```
public void test()
{
    exc(() => 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as

```
() => 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

And ctrl+f for "Specify zero input parameters with empty parentheses:"